# Database Communication in Java

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, communication

I am trying to store, modify, and get variables from a mysql database I have set up. I have figured out how to do this using the sql java library. I am loading my Java program using an external client that does not allow any external libraries. So I have been doing some research and I need to do some sort of communication between PHP and Java.

Let's say I have an int in my Java program:

```
int x = 0;
```

I want to to store this variable in my mysql database.

If someone could please help me or give me an example that gets a variable from java and stores it in a database using php, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: could you give a little more detail. there is always this (have your Java side of things be the server socket, and the PHP side send to it) .....  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

Comment: from java code make a POST Request then handle the variable  with PHP and insert it in your databse.

Comment: java is naturally a more robust software dev environment. since you have already figured out how to write data out to mysql this may be a better place to leave your database code. of course deployment using php is certainly easier that java jars and classes. depends what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1):

You can use web-services (SOAP ..) or the REST method... Although you gonna have to do some research because we can't putt all of the code here plus it will depend on your jws and php files..